# TransactionManagementError "You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block" while using signals, but only during Unit Testing

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-signals

I am getting `TransactionManagementError` when trying to save a Django User model instance and in its `post_save` signal, I'm saving some models that have the user as the foreign key.

The context and error is pretty similar to this question
[django TransactionManagementError when using signals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130507/django-transactionmanagementerror-when-using-signals)

However, in this case, the error occurs **only while unit testing**.

It works well in manual testing, but unit tests fails.

Is there anything that I'm missing?

**Here are the code snippets:**

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def mobileRegister(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        response = {"error": "GET request not accepted!!"}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type="application/json",status=500)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        postdata = json.loads(request.body)
        try:
            # Get POST data which is to be used to save the user
            username = postdata.get('phone')
            password = postdata.get('password')
            email = postdata.get('email',"")
            first_name = postdata.get('first_name',"")
            last_name = postdata.get('last_name',"")
            user = User(username=username, email=email,
                        first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
            user._company = postdata.get('company',None)
            user._country_code = postdata.get('country_code',"+91")
            user.is_verified=True
            user._gcm_reg_id = postdata.get('reg_id',None)
            user._gcm_device_id = postdata.get('device_id',None)
            # Set Password for the user
            user.set_password(password)
            # Save the user
            user.save()
```

signal.py

```
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        company = None
        companycontact = None
        try:   # Try to make userprofile with company and country code provided
            user = User.objects.get(id=instance.id)
            rand_pass = random.randint(1000, 9999)
            company = Company.objects.get_or_create(name=instance._company,user=user)
            companycontact = CompanyContact.objects.get_or_create(contact_type="Owner",company=company,contact_number=instance.username)
            profile = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance,phone=instance.username,verification_code=rand_pass,company=company,country_code=instance._country_code)
            gcmDevice = GCMDevice.objects.create(registration_id=instance._gcm_reg_id,device_id=instance._gcm_reg_id,user=instance)
        except Exception, e:
            pass
```

tests.py

```
class AuthTestCase(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['nextgencatalogs/fixtures.json']
    def setUp(self):
        self.user_data={
            "phone":"0000000000",
            "password":"123",
            "first_name":"Gaurav",
            "last_name":"Toshniwal"
            }

    def test_registration_api_get(self):
        response = self.client.get("/mobileRegister/")
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code,500)

    def test_registration_api_post(self):
        response = self.client.post(path="/mobileRegister/",
                                    data=json.dumps(self.user_data),
                                    content_type="application/json")
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code,201)
        self.user_data['username']=self.user_data['phone']
        user = User.objects.get(username=self.user_data['username'])
        # Check if the company was created
        company = Company.objects.get(user__username=self.user_data['phone'])
        self.assertIsInstance(company,Company)
        # Check if the owner's contact is the same as the user's phone number
        company_contact = CompanyContact.objects.get(company=company,contact_type="owner")
        self.assertEqual(user.username,company_contact[0].contact_number)
```

Traceback:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_registration_api_post (nextgencatalogs.apps.catalogsapp.tests.AuthTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gauravtoshniwal1989/Developer/Web/Server/ngc/nextgencatalogs/apps/catalogsapp/tests.py", line 29, in test_registration_api_post
    user = User.objects.get(username=self.user_data['username'])
  File "/Users/gauravtoshniwal1989/Developer/Web/Server/ngc/ngcvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 151, in get
    return self.get_queryset().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/gauravtoshniwal1989/Developer/Web/Server/ngc/ngcvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 301, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/Users/gauravtoshniwal1989/Developer/Web/Server/ngc/ngcvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 77, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/gauravtoshniwal1989/Developer/Web/Server/ngc/ngcvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 854, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/Users/gauravtoshniwal1989/Developer/Web/Server/ngc/ngcvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 220, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/Users/gauravtoshniwal1989/Developer/Web/Server/ngc/ngcvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 710, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/Users/gauravtoshniwal1989/Developer/Web/Server/ngc/ngcvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 781, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/gauravtoshniwal1989/Developer/Web/Server/ngc/ngcvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 47, in execute
    self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()
  File "/Users/gauravtoshniwal1989/Developer/Web/Server/ngc/ngcvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 365, in validate_no_broken_transaction
    "An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't "
TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: From the docs:
"A TestCase, on the other hand, does not truncate tables after a test. Instead, it encloses the test code in a database transaction that is rolled back at the end of the test. Both explicit commits like transaction.commit() and implicit ones that may be caused by transaction.atomic() are replaced with a nop operation. This guarantees that the rollback at the end of the test restores the database to its initial state."

Comment: I found my problem. There was an IntegrityError exception like this "try: ... except IntegrityError: ..." what I had to do is to use the transaction.atomic inside the try-block: "try: with transaction.atomic(): ... except IntegrityError: ..." now everything works fine.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/
and then search for
"Wrapping atomic in a try/except block allows for natural handling of integrity errors:"

Comment: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21540

Answer (score 345, accepted):

I ran into this same problem myself. This is caused by a quirk in how transactions are handled in the newer versions of Django coupled with a unittest that intentionally triggers an exception.

I had a unittest that checked to make sure a unique column constraint was enforced by purposefully triggering an `IntegrityError` exception:

```
def test_constraint(self):
    try:
        # Duplicates should be prevented.
        models.Question.objects.create(domain=self.domain, slug='barks')
        self.fail('Duplicate question allowed.')
    except IntegrityError:
        pass

    do_more_model_stuff()
```

In Django 1.4, this works fine. However, in Django 1.5/1.6, each test is wrapped in a transaction, so if an exception occurs, it breaks the transaction until you explicitly roll it back. Therefore, any further ORM operations in that transaction, such as my `do_more_model_stuff()`, will fail with that `django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError` exception.

Like caio mentioned in the comments, the solution is to capture your exception with `transaction.atomic` like:

```
from django.db import transaction
def test_constraint(self):
    try:
        # Duplicates should be prevented.
        with transaction.atomic():
            models.Question.objects.create(domain=self.domain, slug='barks')
        self.fail('Duplicate question allowed.')
    except IntegrityError:
        pass
```

That will prevent the purposefully-thrown exception from breaking the entire unittest's transaction.

Comment: Also consider just declaring your test class as a TransactionTestCase rather than just TestCase.

Comment: This reply helps resolve my problem, too! Thanks for that! However, I am also curious *HOW* you solved this problem when you encountered that? Did you investigate yourself? Or you sent an email to the user list? Or what..?

Comment: Oh, I found the related document from another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130507/django-transactionmanagementerror-when-using-signals). The document is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/).

Comment: For me, I _already_ had a `transaction.atomic()` block, but I got this error and I had no idea why. I took this answer's advice and put a _nested_ atomic block inside of my atomic block around the trouble-area. After that, it gave a detailed error of the integrity error I hit, allowing me to fix my code and do what I was trying to do.

Comment: @mkoistinen `TestCase` is inheriting from `TransactionTestCase` so no need to change that. If you don't operate on DB in test use `SimpleTestCase`.

Comment: @bns you're missing the point of the comment.  Yes `TestCase` inherits from `TransactionTestCase` but its behavior is quite different: it wraps each test method in a transaction.  `TransactionTestCase`, on the other hand, is perhaps misleadingly named: it truncates tables to reset the db -- the naming seems to reflect that you can test transactions within a test, not that the test is wrapped as a transaction!

Comment: This does not work if the exception catching is happening inside of the function being called such as `do_more_model_stuff` in this case. For example, I want to run a function that operates on the model and handles errors. None of these suggestions seem to avoid the `TransactionManagementError` described

Comment: Be careful, if you need to use `setUpTestData` you can't use it with `TransactionTestCase` it needs to be used with `TestCase`. 
 While testing my integrity error for unique group, I had to wrap the `save` call inside the `with atomic()` block

Answer (score 63):

Since @mkoistinen never made [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458387/transactionmanagementerror-you-cant-execute-queries-until-the-end-of-the-atom#comment44444356_23326971) an answer, I'll post the suggestion so people won't have to dig through comments.

> consider just declaring your test class as a TransactionTestCase rather than just TestCase.

From the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase): A TransactionTestCase may call commit and rollback and observe the effects of these calls on the database.

Comment: +1 for this, but, as the docs say, "Django’s TestCase class is a more commonly used subclass of TransactionTestCase". To answer the original question, shouldn't we use SimpleTestCase instead of TestCase? SimpleTestCase doesn't have the atomic database features.

Comment: @daigorocub When inheriting from `SimpleTestCase`, `allow_database_queries = True` must be added inside the test class, so it doesn't spit an `AssertionError("Database queries aren't allowed in SimpleTestCase...",)`.

Comment: This is the answer that works best for me as I was trying to test for integrityerror will be raised and then subsequently I needed to run more database save queries

Comment: Important to keep in mind that `TransactionTestCase` can be significantly slower than a traditional `TestCase`.

Answer (score 25):

If using pytest-django you can pass `transaction=True` to the `django_db` decorator to avoid this error.

See https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#testing-transactions

> Django itself has the TransactionTestCase which allows you to test
>   transactions and will flush the database between tests to isolate
>   them. The downside of this is that these tests are much slower to set up due to the required flushing of the database. pytest-django also supports this style of tests, which you can select using an argument to the django_db mark:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
def test_spam():
    pass  # test relying on transactions
```

Comment: I had an issue with this solution, I had initial data in my DB (added by migrations). This solution flush the database, so other tests dependent on this initial data started to fail.

Answer (score 13):

Here is another way to do it, based on the answer to this question:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    self.assertRaises(IntegrityError, models.Question.objects.create, **{'domain':self.domain, 'slug':'barks'})
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was caused but not calling `super().tearDownClass()`

```
class TnsFileViewSetTestCase(APITestCase):
    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(self):
        super().tearDownClass()    # without this line we will get TransactionManagementError
        for tnsfile in TnsFile.objects.all():
            tnsfile.file.delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, but `with transaction.atomic()` and `TransactionTestCase` didn't work for me.

`python manage.py test -r`  instead of `python manage.py test` is ok for me, maybe the order of execution is crucial

then i find a doc about [Order in which tests are executed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/overview/#order-in-which-tests-are-executed), It mentions which test will run first.

So, I use TestCase for database interaction, `unittest.TestCase` for other simple test, it works now!

Answer (score 1):

For me, the proposed fixes did not work. In my tests, I open some subprocesses with `Popen` to analyze/lint migrations (e.g. one test checks if there are no model changes).

For me, subclassing from `SimpleTestCase` instead of `TestCase` did do the trick.

Note that `SimpleTestCase` doesn't allow to use the database.

While this does not answer the original question, I hope this helps some people anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
def test_wrong_user_country_db_constraint(self):
        """
        Check whether or not DB constraint doesnt allow to save wrong country code in DB.
        """
        self.test_user_data['user_country'] = 'XX'
        expected_constraint_name = "country_code_within_list_of_countries_check"

        with transaction.atomic():
            with self.assertRaisesRegex(IntegrityError, expected_constraint_name) as cm:
                get_user_model().objects.create_user(**self.test_user_data)

        self.assertFalse(
            get_user_model().objects.filter(email=self.test_user_data['email']).exists()
        )
```

```
with transaction.atomic() seems do the job correct
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna perform multiple queries, this is the way to do it

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_multiple queries_where_one_fails():
    # Double transaction wrap is needed
    with transaction.atomic():
             # do a process with some failing query
    with transaction.atomic():
        assert Model.objects.count() == 0
    # rest of assertions
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Pricing(models.Model):
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=1)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.price)

class Services(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
pricing = models.OneToOneField(Pricing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0.0)
categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name="services")
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

In my case you are getting this error in the function where you are testing an instance onetoonefield : where you're creating a price instance and adding it into 2 service instances and getting this error:

Solution : Inside your function do this

```
with transaction.atomic():
        with self.assertRaises(IntegrityError):
            service = Services.objects.create(name = "Some Service", pricing= self.pricing1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error on running unit tests in my create_test_data function using django 1.9.7.  It worked in earlier versions of django.

It looked like this:

```
cls.localauth,_ = Organisation.objects.get_or_create(organisation_type=cls.orgtypeLA, name='LA for test', email_general='test@test.com', address='test', postcode='test', telephone='test')
cls.chamber,_ = Organisation.objects.get_or_create(organisation_type=cls.orgtypeC, name='chamber for test', email_general='test@test.com', address='test', postcode='test', telephone='test')
cls.lawfirm,_ = Organisation.objects.get_or_create(organisation_type=cls.orgtypeL, name='lawfirm for test', email_general='test@test.com', address='test', postcode='test', telephone='test')

cls.chamber.active = True
cls.chamber.save()

cls.localauth.active = True
cls.localauth.save()    <---- error here

cls.lawfirm.active = True
cls.lawfirm.save()
```

My solution was to use update_or_create instead:

```
cls.localauth,_ = Organisation.objects.update_or_create(organisation_type=cls.orgtypeLA, name='LA for test', email_general='test@test.com', address='test', postcode='test', telephone='test', defaults={'active': True})
cls.chamber,_ = Organisation.objects.update_or_create(organisation_type=cls.orgtypeC, name='chamber for test', email_general='test@test.com', address='test', postcode='test', telephone='test', defaults={'active': True})
cls.lawfirm,_ = Organisation.objects.update_or_create(organisation_type=cls.orgtypeL, name='lawfirm for test', email_general='test@test.com', address='test', postcode='test', telephone='test', defaults={'active': True})
```

Comment: `get_or_create()` works as well, it seems it's the .save() it doesnt like inside a transaction.atomic() decorated function (mine failed with just 1 call in there).

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @kdazzle is correct. I didnt try it because people said that 'Django’s TestCase class is a more commonly used subclass of TransactionTestCase' so I thought it was the same use one or another. But the [blog of Jahongir Rahmonov](http://rahmonov.me/posts/testcase-vs-transactiontestcase-in-django/) explained it better:

> the TestCase class wraps the tests within two nested atomic() blocks:
>   one for the whole class and one for each test. This is where
>   TransactionTestCase should be used. It does not wrap the tests with
>   atomic() block and thus you can test your special methods that require
>   a transaction without any problem.

EDIT: It didn't work, I thought yes, but NO.

In 4 years they could fixed this.......................................

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue.

In My Case I was doing this

```
author.tasks.add(tasks)
```

so converting it to

```
author.tasks.add(*tasks)
```

Removed that error.