# Django 1.6.1 : Transaction error. You can't execute queries until the end of the atomic block in unitest

Tags: django, postgresql, django-unittest

Django 1.6.1 on Windows with Postgres

I m using unittest to test a view that upload a .cfg file to server. I am facing 2 error called

(1) TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the atomic block.
(2) OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

I am writing down my view and test below.

Views.py

```
def upload(request, device_id):

    owner=account.objects.get(user=request.user)
    dev = get_object_or_404(device, pk=device_id, owner=owner)

    state = 0

    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = UploadConfigForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_file = form.save(commit=False)

            #now ask the device to download the config file
            sess, action, action_opt = add_device_action(device=dev, action=Action.AC_CONFIG_FILE_SET)

            #get the action related to this file
            if action_opt:
                new_file.act = action_opt
            else:
                new_file.act = action

            new_file.save()
            form.save_m2m()

            #add the payload to the action
            if action_opt:
                action_opt.payload = new_file.payload()
                action_opt.save ()
            else:
                action.payload = new_file.payload()
                action.save ()


            if settings.RENDER_JSON_INSTEAD_OF_HTML:
                # Render as an json response
                resp = action.descriptor()
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps(resp), content_type="application/json")

            else:
                # Redirect to the document list after POST
                # return HttpResponseRedirect('..')
                state = 1

    else:
        form = UploadConfigForm() # A empty, unbound form
```

tests.py

```
class DevAPISimulDevTests(TestCase):
    """
    Class that test the device API
    """
    fixtures = ['test_auth.json', 'test_users.json', 'test_device.json']

    def setUp(self):
        """

        """
        ret = self.client.login(username='cws', password='cws123')
        self.assertEqual(ret, True)


    def test_api_sim_usr_upload_config_file(self):
        """
        simulate the upload of the config file ba the user. submit with a file that is ok
        """


        logger.debug('test_upload_config_file')

        dev_id = 1
        dev = device.objects.get(pk=dev_id)

        url = reverse('device-upload', kwargs={'device_id':dev_id})
        myfile = open('device/fixtures/cfg_ok.csr','r')

            # with transaction.atomic():
        response = self.client.post(url, {'config_file':myfile})
        logger.debug('POST[%s]:[%s]', url, response.status_code)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        ad = json.loads(response.content)

        # Check the ad we think we should receive. 
        self.assertEqual(ad[Action.AD_EP_URL_BASE], settings.API_BASE_URL)
        self.assertEqual(ad[Action.AD_EP_ACTION], settings.API_EP_ACK)
        self.assertEqual(ad[Action.AD_EP_ERROR], settings.API_EP_ERR)
        self.assertEqual(ad[Action.AD_DEVICE_CODE], dev.access_code)
        self.assertEqual(ad[Action.AD_ACTION_CODE], Action.AC_ACKNOWLEDGE)
        self.assertIsNone(ad.get(Action.AD_ACTION_PAYLOAD))
        self.assertIsNone(ad.get(Action.AD_ACTION_WAIT))


        # Check the DB
        # We should have 1 session
        self.assertEqual(dev.session_set.count(), 1)
        sess = Session.objects.first()
        self.assertEqual(sess.state, Session.STATE_SMS_SENT)

        # We should have 2 actions more
        self.assertEqual(sess.action_set.count(), 2)

        # The first action should have the same token as in the SMS and the status should be in progress
        first_act = sess.action_set.first()
        self.assertEqual(first_act.next_token, ad[Action.AD_EP_TOKEN])
        self.assertEqual(first_act.status, Action.STATUS_IN_PROGRESS)

        # The second action should have the same token as in the SMS and the status should be queued
        next_act = sess.action_set.last()
        self.assertEqual(next_act.current_token, ad[Action.AD_EP_TOKEN])
        self.assertEqual(next_act.status, Action.STATUS_QUEUED)

        # test the status
        status_should_be = {u'0': {u'state': u'in progress', u'state_label': u'processing', u'label': u'contacting device'},
                            u'1': {u'state': u'queued', u'state_label': u'not started', u'label': u'uploading config file to device'}}

        self.test_sessionstatus(status_should_be)
        return ad

        # except IntegrityError:
        #     pass



    def test_api_sim_dev_init_session (self):
        """
        API : simulate the device receiving the first AD trhough SMS and initiating the session
        """
        # try:


        logger.debug('test_api_sim_dev_init_session')
            # with transaction.atomic():
        ad = self.test_api_sim_usr_upload_config_file()

        # validate that the url is correct
        url = reverse('device-api_ack', kwargs={'token':ad [Action.AD_EP_TOKEN]})

        url2 = ''.join (['/device/', ad [Action.AD_EP_TOKEN], '/', ad[Action.AD_EP_ACTION]])
        self.assertEqual(url, url2)


        # Simulate the device processing the first ad of the session
        # retrieve the next command from the server
        response = self.client.get(url)
        logger.debug('GET[%s]:[%s]', url, response.status_code)

        # check the answer
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        ad2 = json.loads(response.content)
        self.assertTrue(type(ad2) is dict)

        # Check the ad we think we should receive.
        self.assertEqual(ad2[Action.AD_ACTION_CODE], Action.AC_CONFIG_FILE_SET)
        self.assertEqual(ad2[Action.AD_EP_ACTION], settings.API_EP_CFG)
        self.assertTrue(type(ad2[Action.AD_ACTION_PAYLOAD]) is dict)
            #TODO: will need on time to understand why this asssrt fail.
        # self.assertContains(ad2[Action.AD_ACTION_PAYLOAD]['url'], '.csr')
        self.assertIsNone(ad2.get(Action.AD_DEVICE_CODE))
        self.assertIsNone(ad2.get(Action.AD_EP_URL_BASE))
        self.assertIsNone(ad2.get(Action.AD_EP_ERROR))


        # Check the DB
        # We should have 1 session in STATE_WAIT_DEV_REQ
        dev_id = 1
        dev = device.objects.get(pk=dev_id)

        self.assertEqual(dev.session_set.count(), 1)
        sess = Session.objects.first()
        self.assertEqual(sess.state, Session.STATE_WAIT_DEV_REQ)

        # We should still have 2 actions
        self.assertEqual(sess.action_set.count(), 2)

        # The first action should have a status done
        first_act = sess.action_set.first()
        self.assertEqual(first_act.status, Action.STATUS_DONE)
        self.assertEqual(first_act.next_token, ad[Action.AD_EP_TOKEN])

        # The second action should have the same token as in the SMS and the status should be queued
        next_act = sess.action_set.last()
        self.assertEqual(next_act.current_token, ad[Action.AD_EP_TOKEN])
        self.assertEqual(next_act.next_token, ad2[Action.AD_EP_TOKEN])
        self.assertEqual(next_act.status, Action.STATUS_IN_PROGRESS)

        # test the status
        status_should_be = {u'0': {u'state': u'done', u'state_label': u'done', u'label': u'contacting device'},
                                    u'1': {u'state': u'in progress', u'state_label': u'processing', u'label': u'uploading config file to device'}}
        self.test_sessionstatus(status_should_be)

        return ad2
```

Please suggest what I am doing wrong here, If code being pasted here does not concern errors, please suggest what code causes this error , as I cant figure out the origin of this errors..

Comment: maybe this helps:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458387/transactionmanagementerror-you-cant-execute-queries-until-the-end-of-the-atom

Comment: visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458387/transactionmanagementerror-you-cant-execute-queries-until-the-end-of-the-atom

Answer (score 0):

might want to add:

```
'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,
```

under

```
DATABASES = {
 'default': {
     'ENGINE':whatever,
     'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,
  }
}
```

Comment: Please note the impact of `ATOMIC_REQUEST` = True, it can slow down your site. 

While the simplicity of this transaction model is appealing, it also makes it inefficient when traffic increases. Opening a transaction for every view has some overhead. The impact on performance depends on the query patterns of your application and on how well your database handles locking. From the docs:   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/transactions/#tying-transactions-to-http-requests