# exception in tests after upgrading from django 1.5 to 1.7

Tags: python, django, exception, upgrade

this is the test that broke:

```
def test_registering_user_twice_cause_error_msg(self):

    user=User(name='pyRock',email='python@rocks.com')
    user.save()

    #create the request used to test the view
    self.request.session = {}
    self.request.method = 'POST'
    self.request.POST = {
        'email':'python@rocks.com',
        'name':'pyRock',
        'stripe_token':'...',
        'last_4_digits':'4242',
        'password':'bad_password',
        'ver_password':'bad_password'
    }

    expected_form=UserForm(self.request.POST)
    expected_form.is_valid()
    expected_form.addError('python@rocks.com is already a member')

    #create the expected html
    html = render_to_response(
        'register.html',
        {
            'form': expected_form,
            'months': range(1, 12),
            'publishable': settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE,
            'soon': soon(),
            'user': None,
            'years': list(range(2011, 2036)),
        }
    )

    #mock out stripe so we don't hit their server
    with mock.patch('stripe.Customer') as stripe_mock:

        config = {'create.return_value': mock.Mock()}
        stripe_mock.configure_mock(**config)

        #run the test
        resp = register(self.request)

        #verify that we did things correctly

        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
        self.assertEqual(self.request.session, {})
        self.assertEqual(resp.content, html.content)

        #assert there is no records in the database.
        users = User.objects.filter(email="python@rocks.com")
        self.assertEqual(len(users), 1)
```

So when running the test it throws the following:

```
ERROR: test_registering_user_twice_cause_error_msg (payments.tests.RegisterPageTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/1111/_realpython/d3/django_ecommerce/payments/tests.py", line 278, in test_registering_user_twice_cause_error_msg
    self.assertEqual(len(users), 1)
  File "/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/d317/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 122, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/d317/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 966, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/d317/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 265, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/d317/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 700, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/d317/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 786, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/d317/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 59, in execute
    self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()
  File "/Users/1111/.virtualenvs/d317/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 386, in validate_no_broken_transaction
    "An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't "
TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.
```

I read a couple answers about Django wrapping up each test in a transaction, but I can't make anything out of it as I am a Django noob, and the code above is the tutorial.

It's even more interesting that the exception happens in the assertion. If I remove it the test passes, even with the query `users = User.objects.filter(email="python@rocks.com")` present. However, if I reference `users` in some way, say just `print users` the test breaks again.

So what's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [TransactionManagementError "You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block" while using signals, but only during Unit Testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458387/transactionmanagementerror-you-cant-execute-queries-until-the-end-of-the-atom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So what's going on?

As stated, [this is a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458387/transactionmanagementerror-you-cant-execute-queries-until-the-end-of-the-atom).

But I'll separately address the reason it breaks if you access `users`. The reason this happens is that Django database calls are lazy and delays execution until you finally use query.

So if you never use or iterate through `users` it will save you a database call. This is why it looked like it was working, was because if you remove `len(users)` it never needs the result of `users`,so won't query for it.