# Django test: TransactionManagementError: You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

Django newbie here. I'm trying to implement unit tests for a simple API I developed. Below you can find my test implementation which works fine:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from my_app.models import MyModel


class TestMyViewSet(TestCase):
    """
    Unit tests for endpoints in MyViewSet.
    """
    fixtures = ['my_app/fixtures/data.yaml']

    def setUp(self):
        # Making setup for the test case here.


    def test_post_my_resource(self):

        # Checking that fixture is loaded correctly.
        self.assertEqual(MyModel.objects.all().count(),1)

        request_body = {
            'my_resource': "input_for_my_resource"
        }

        response = self.client.post('/my_resources/', data=request_body)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201)
        # self.assertEqual(MyModel.objects.all().count(),2)
```

But when I removed the last line `self.assertEqual(MyModel.objects.all().count(),2)` from the comment to test that `my_resource` is created successfully on the corresponding model by checking the number of instances, I got an error stating the following:

> TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

PS: I come across the following question: [TransactionManagementError “You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block” while using signals, but only during Unit Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21458387/transactionmanagementerror-you-cant-execute-queries-until-the-end-of-the-atom) but I'm not sure what's happening in my case is the same.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Apparently, moving from `django.test.TestCase` to `django.test.TransactionTestCase` solved the issue. Here are some important points regarding the differences between `django.test.TestCase` and `django.test.TransactionTestCase`:

> `TransactionTestCase` and `TestCase` are identical except for the manner in which the database is reset to a known state and the ability for test code to test the effects of commit and rollback:
>
> - `TransactionTestCase` resets the database after the test runs by truncating all tables. A `TransactionTestCase` may call commit and rollback and observe the effects of these calls on the database.
> - A `TestCase`, on the other hand, does not truncate tables after a test. Instead, it encloses the test code in a database transaction that is rolled back at the end of the test. This guarantees that the rollback at the end of the test restores the database to its initial state.

Here you can find more details from the docs [TransactionTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase)

Comment: You can also make use of transaction.atomic by importing transaction from django.db