# pytest: Test database constraints

Tags: python, django, pytest

I wrote the following test for my Django application. The IntegrationDaily model has a constraint of max. 100 capacity. Therefore the entry will fail "on purpose". However, `pytest.raises(Exception)` seems to be the wrong approach to validate that. I also tried to import `TransactionManagementError` instead but that didn't solve it either.

```
import pytest

from tests.factories.spaces import IntegrationDailyFactory
from myapp.spaces.models import IntegrationDaily


def describe_element_capacity_validation():
    def with_is_failling():
        with pytest.raises(Exception) as exc:
            daily_element = IntegrationDailyFactory(capacity=300)

        assert IntegrationDaily.objects.count() == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Which Error is raised when it's more than 100? I assume it's [`IntegrityError`](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/IntegrityError).

```
from django.db import IntegrityError

with pytest.raises(IntegrityError) as e:
    daily_element = IntegrationDailyFactory(capacity=300)
```

Comment: The challenge here is that I am running into that error once I try that: `django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.` Currently reading about `@pytest.mark.django_db`, maybe that can solve it?

Comment: this might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23326971/1344855

Comment: Thank you everyone. Adding `@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)` solved my problem.